# Adding a the block on checkout_cart_index

Tags: magento2

i tried add a new block in checkout cart of magento 2 is possible from of my module in this moment I have this.

```
<my_module>
->view
-->frotend
--->layout
----->checkout_cart_index.xml
```

In the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="CARLOS_Cart::form/js.phtml" name="form.js"/>
</body>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the block in a container for it to be rendered. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="CARLOS_Cart::form/js.phtml" name="form.js"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `checkout_cart_index.xml` in your module and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Customblock" name="customblock" template="Namespace_Module::customblock.phtml" after="-">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body>
</page>
```